# How to get current logged in user in django with a custom abstract user

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm trying to get the user which is actively making a post request to my api. I am using this to associate a posting with the user that makes it. However, when I make a post, it always returns Anonymous User. I am able to authenticate, sign up, and login properly. Is there any other way I could go about this?

I am using django allauth to authenticate with email

I have the following User model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=78)
full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

objects = CustomUserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return(self.email)
```

The following is my Listing model:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
listingId = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)
streetAddress = models.CharField(max_length=120)
city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
state = models.CharField(max_length=120)
zipCode = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)
price = models.IntegerField(max_length=6)
deposit = models.IntegerField(max_length=6, default=0)
description = models.TextField()
rooms = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
bathrooms = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
rentalType = models.IntegerField(choices=RentalType.choices(), default=RentalType.HOUSE)
amenities = models.TextField()
listingUser = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='listings', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
dateAvailable = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.streetAddress
```

And my views.py for the Listing model

```
class ListingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Listing.objects.all()
serializer_class = ListingSerializer

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    custom = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    user = get_user_model()
    print(self.request.user)
    #serializer.save(listingUser=self.request.user)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.list(request, *args, *kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Edit: I am setting up django on a different server than my front-end. Not sure if that might make a difference to my current approach. I tried researching the request.user method. From what I understood, it accesses the default user model.

Settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'corsheaders',
    'listing',
    'users',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth.socialaccount', 
]

REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.UserSerializer',
}

REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
        'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.UserSerializer',
    }


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use session authentication and then you can get user by `request.user`.

in settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication

class ListingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Listing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListingSerializer
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        custom = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
        user = get_user_model()
        print(self.request.user)
        #serializer.save(listingUser=self.request.user)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, *kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I have tried using request.user in my views.py; that returns Anonymous User

Comment: Did you use session authentication? That keeps user logged in until the session expires.

Comment: I tried using the session authentication as well which returned an Anonymous user again. I made sure to apply migrations after updating the settings and views.py. I apologize if I am making a small mistake somewhere this is my first time using django. I have edited the original post to show the added variables to settings.py

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I am currently using token authentication, I tried to use session authentication with your suggested edits as well and it did not work. Thank you for the help so far tho

Comment: did you solve it? because seems like you accepted the answer. let me know please